# Angular : calling API multiple times parallely throwing 500 status

Tags: angular, typescript, api, httprequest

I have a parent component that loads child components in different tabs as per the no of tabs.

my code for parent component HTML file is :

```
<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p >Details</p>
        <tabset [justified]="true" class="ie-fix-flex">
            <tab *ngFor="let item of dNumbers">
                <ng-template tabHeading >{{ item.Number }}</ng-template >
                <div>
                    <app-details [Number]="item.Number"></app-details>
                </div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

my child component getting Number correctly and let if the loop run 4 times for 4 deal numbers. My ngOnIt calls 4 times and thus it calls my API 4 times paralelly resulting in error codes.

```
 @Input('Number') Number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Num = this.commonService.encryptData(this.Number, this.key, this.iv);
    this.getDetails();
  }

  async getDetails() {
    this.proService.getDetails(this.Num)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.detailData = data;
      })
  }
```

getDetails() of proService method calls my API. I haven't used any promise or async await in my API. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

I want to return data from every calls. sometimes it gives data in 1 tab or 2 tab but not in all tabs. It ended with 500 status.

Comment: Do you also get an error message of any kind? Is this your backend or is it an API someone else hosts that you are calling?

Comment: No I am just getting 500 status for few of my numbers. Also I am using someone else's API and API has no issues with the requested data.

Comment: Am not sure how you are using the ````detailData```` variable, but try using the async pipe, coz, angular will take care of subscribing and unsubscribing.

Comment: You can create a service which holds the state. The service loads the data from API once and stores into i.e. a BehaviorSubject. Then components subscribe to this BehaviourSubject and not directly to the API call.

Comment: Thankyou all for ur valuable suggestions. I tried these ways but unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: hi all, I got the issue actually the API is built in .net so that was not supporting parallel calls. I write the click event on tabs and load the data on that event one by one. it is working fine now. Thankyou